# How to get git to work through a proxy and IntelliJ Idea?

Tags: git, proxy, intellij-idea

Where do I configure the proxy settings for GIT in IntelliJ Idea? I've gotten the proxy settings working for the plugins, but I just can't find it for GIT; and the help files only mention subversion.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You have to configure proxy for git and not for intelliJ, intelliJ will just call the git command line.

`git config --global http.proxy yourProxy:port` should do it.

Comment: On my case i had to add one additional step to make it work -> On Intellij -> Preferences -> Search git -> choose git -> ssh executable -> to native. Instead of the built in. This cause the bitbucket is using ssh.

Comment: After adding the proxy using `git config --global http.proxy http://username:password@host:port` my clone attempt failed due to the self-signed certificate presented by the proxy. This answer provided the solution to the certificate error: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11622001/669645

Answer (score 3):

To be complete I would like to add how to hop over a proxy to get to git server or secured sites using ssh, like for example private github repositories.

For intellij when using this option, you must select to use the *native* ssh implementation in  Project Settings --> Version Control --> VCSs --> Git --> SSH Executable

We use a tool called corkscrew. This is available for both CygWin (through setup from the cygwin homepage) and Linux using your favorite packaging tool.

For MacOSX I refer to this [blogpost](http://blog.strotos.com/?p=15) to install it on you Mac.

The command line is as follows :

```
corkscrew <proxyhost> <proxyport> <targethost> <targetport> <authfile>
```

The proxyhost and proxyport are the coordinates of the https proxy.

The targethost and targetport is the location of the host to tunnel to.

The authfile is a textfile with 1 line containing your proxy server username/password separated by a colon

e.g:

```
abc:very_secret
```

Installation for using git:// protocol : usually not needed!

- Create a helper script to create the tunnel

Create a script **~/bin/gitproxy**  which contains :

```
#!/bin/bash
corkscrew proxy.colo.elex.be 3128 github.com 9148 ~/.ssh/proxy_auth
```

- Create the proxy_auth file in the ~/.ssh/ folder

Make sure it is safe from prying eyes.

- Set an environment variable to define the proxy command for git

  $ export GIT_PROXY_COMMAND=/home/pti/bin/gitproxy

You might place this in a section or script sourced from .bashrc which dynamically detects if you are behind the proxy or not. If the variable is not defined then git will work as usual.

- test it

Installation for using "normal" ssh protocol for git communication
By adding this to the ~/.ssh/config
this trick can be used for normal ssh connections

Host gitproxy
  HostName github.com
  Port 22
  ProxyCommand corkscrew   %h %p ~/.ssh/proxy_auth

enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

In my case i had to set proxy through MSDOS command line, then it pushed results without 407 error

```
SET HTTP_PROXY=http://user:passs@proxydomain.com:portnumber
```

Comment: Be aware that reboot will erase this conf , therefore if you want to set it for ever, you should add it to system variables menu . Here is a link for this settings procedure for windows.
https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm