# Https is not supported in libcurl window alertnative than using CURLOPT_CAINFO

Tags: c++, winapi, libcurl

We are using libcurl (7.3.6) in our application. API call for "Https URL" giving "curle_ssl_cacert error". I have been able to resolve this using

```
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "PATH\\curl-ca-bundle.crt");
```

but we don't want to maintain this file in our application. Is there any way we can directly access from OS or from an alternative location?

Comment: On Linux build libcurl with NSS support. On Windows build libcurl with schannel support and disable openssl. Look [here](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html) for more details.

Comment: If you're on macOS or Windows, you can build with the native TLS libraries and use their native cert stores. If you're on Linux, you need to use a separate CA cert file but your Linux distributions provide/update them...

Answer (score 0):

For Windows,

If you want to use windows own "CA certificate", You need to rebuild curl to with schannel backend instead(aka "winssl"). It will access from windows cert store by default. Openssl does not support to use windows system certificate on its own(see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37551409/configure-curl-to-use-default-system-cert-store)), and must specify the certificate in PEM format, or set the default certificate when building libcurl with parameter `--with-ca-bundle` and `--with-ca-path`.

For Linux,

According to the [document](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html):

> If libcurl was built with NSS support, then depending on the OS
>   distribution, it is probably required to take some additional steps to
>   use the system-wide CA cert db. RedHat ships with an additional
>   module, libnsspem.so, which enables NSS to read the OpenSSL PEM CA
>   bundle.