How would I let PHP 8.3.10 access my local windows certificates?
My server doesn't have an SSL certificate for more context.
I've only observed this issue in IIS & the PHP interactive shell, here's some example code you can use to replicate my issue
<?php
 $ch = curl_init();
 $url = "https://example.com";
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 $response = curl_exec($ch);
 echo $response;

I can make successful http requests only over the HTTP protocol with both cURL and file_get_contents() but I get errors when using file_get_contents() when making a request to an https URL and nothing when using cURL also making a request to an https URL.
I've tried to mess with openssl.cafile and curl.cainfo with no success from this answer.
Also set allow_url_fopen = On & allow_url_include = On in php.ini and enabled the php openSSL extension per this PHP documentation

What errors do you get exactly?

Here are the errors I get when using file_get_contents() as I get an empty response with cURL: PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:0A00010B:SSL routines::wrong version number in pxy.php on line 8 PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto in pxy.php on line 8 PHP Warning:  file_get_contents($url): Failed to open stream: operation failed in pxy.php on line 8

Why did you delete your own answer? You should simply accept it to close the discussion.

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37551409/configure-curl-to-use-default-system-cert-store-on-windows

@LexLi Turns out that my answer didn't fix my issue as a whole. Windows has a certificate store and PHP's configuration mentions that Most users should not specify a value for this directive as PHP will attempt to use the OS-managed cert stores in its absence. and a .pem file isn't anything to the operating system's reliable certificate store

@AndrewHenle seems genuinely helpful, like I feel relived. THANK YOUUU!!

Solution
I would much rather have this in my php.ini but oh well, You have to set CURLOPT_SSL_OPTIONS to CURLSSLOPT_NATIVE_CA.
Example in php:
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://www.example.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_OPTIONS, CURLSSLOPT_NATIVE_CA);
curl_exec($ch);

Thanks to @Andrew Henle
sadly I dont know of a file_get_contents() solution besides my old one referenced below.

Old: It turns out that I had to set the openssl.cafile and curl.cainfo to the cacert.pem file you can get here (Or anything other certificate bundle) and when you have PHP running in IIS you have to give the current app pool identity read permissions to the certificate that way PHP's configuration can actually read it.
NOTE: THIS DID NOT FIX MY ISSUE AS A WHOLE AND I GOT AN SSL VERSION ERROR PRETTY OFTEN

There can be quite a few things broken on Windows, and you need such investigations to find that things just work differently on Windows, and a dependency might not work reliably. I guess that's why Microsoft stopped supporting PHP on IIS/Windows, https://docs.lextudio.com/phpmanager/getting-started/supported-platforms. You might consider simply hosting PHP web apps on Linux.

I'm going make my own HTTPS client extension that uses windows native APIs and not these run down Unix libraries.
