# Git - The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to clone from Github by using both Github Desktop and the git shell but keep on getting this error:

```
Cloning into 'C:\Users\John Doe\workspace\MyProject'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/JohnDoe/MyProject.git/': 
schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error (0x80092012) - 
The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate.
```

Same problem when pulling an existing repository.

I've already tried to upload SSH keys found in `~/.ssh/github-ssh.pub` to Github settings but it doesn't help anything.

**EDIT:** Just checked, it will happen even if I try to clone a non-existent repository.

Comment: To work with ssh keys you need to change the URL from `https://github.com/JohnDoe/MyProject.git` to `git@github.com:JohnDoe/MyProject.git`.

Answer (score 72):

This error is also commonly hit when you're on a corporate network that performs MITM on all traffic, and then blocks the revocation check.
While, obviously, the ideal situation is to not block the checks (or at least, to a whitelist of urls), it may be required to work around this problem.

One option is, as in the first part of Mike's answer, [using the OpenSSL bindings instead](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/blob/master/docs/known-issues.md#certificate-revocation-check-fails---3326).  While this works, it requires manual maintenance of the certificate lists, which may not be practical in extreme situations (say, new root certs issued every day, although this is unlikely).

The other option, akin to the second part of Mike's answer, is disabling revocation checking.
Recent versions, 2.19 and above, of git-for-windows provides an [`http.schannelCheckRevoke` setting](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/blob/master/Documentation/config.txt#L2265-L2271):

> Used to enforce or disable certificate revocation checks in cURL
>       when http.sslBackend is set to "schannel". Defaults to `true` if
>       unset. Only necessary to disable this if Git consistently errors
>       and the message is about checking the revocation status of a
>       certificate. This option is ignored if cURL lacks support for
>       setting the relevant SSL option at runtime.

... so you can simply disable checking for revocation in the first place:
`git config --global http.schannelCheckRevoke false`

Note that, unlike disabling SSL entirely, this is not inherently less secure than using Mike's answer for specific repositories: if you capture and configure an empty revocation list (the usual case), you have effectively disabled revocation checking.  [Disabling revocation checking only becomes a risk in the case of private-key compromise](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/69350/website-certificate-revocation-check-big-deal) (at some point in the chain), which is rare and difficult.

Note, also, that in a corporate MITM setting, revocation checking is being performed for you: no proxy worth using would issue a cert for an invalid or (known) compromised certificate.

Comment: So, this happens due to MITM checks. But why does it not fail when using the OpenSSL backend?

Comment: @ctwx - I'm not completely sure.  My guess is that either OpenSSL has revocation checking disabled by default (note that the option is schannel-specific), or it's more tolerant to certain errors (for example, just ignoring 404s).  This is because revocation checking is inherently problematic - you don't have any guarantee that you can (successfully) contact issuing servers for validity status.

Answer (score 58):

It's always a bad idea to disable certificate verification (setting `http.sslVerify` to `false`).

I think the problem here is that, when you installed *git*, you opted to use the *Windows Secure Channel* library instead of the *OpenSSL* library:

[image: Git installation options]

As pointed out by @CurtJ.Sampson (thanks, Curt!), you can switch to using the *OpenSSL* library instead, which will fix your issue. This can be done with the following command:

```
git config --global http.sslBackend openssl
```

Alternatively, you can re-install *git*, specifying the *OpenSSL* library in the process.

Don't forget to turn *git* SSL verification back on with:

```
git config --global http.sslVerify true
```

**Update**: If you're using self-signed or corporate certificates on your own *git* server, and you get an error when attempting to connect to it (such as *self signed certificate in certificate chain*, or *SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate*), then the solution is to tell *git* where to find the *CA* that was used to sign that site's certificate. You can do this with the following configuration command:

```
git config --global http.{your site's URL here}.sslcainfo "{path to your cert file}"
```

For example, if you have a local git server at `https://my.gitserver.com/` and the *CA* that signed the site's certificate is in `C:\Certs\MyCACert.crt`, then you'll need to enter:

```
git config --global http.https://my.gitserver.com/.sslcainfo "C:\Certs\MyCACert.crt"
```

This is a more robust solution compared to adding your CA certificate to *git*'s bundled `ca-bundle.crt` file, since that file will be overwritten when you next update *git*.

Comment: You don't need to reinstall: you can `git config --global http.sslBackend openssl` to switch your account on that machine to use OpenSSL, or set it to `schannel` to switch it back. `git config --list` will tell you the current settings; the later ones override the earlier ones.

Comment: Sad to say, when I switch to OpenSSL I end up with a different error: "self signed certificate in certificate chain." (This may well be related to the proxy configuration, though I'm using the same corporate proxy, accessed via HTTP, in both cases.)

Comment: @CurtJ.Sampson Thanks for pointing out the `http.sslBackend` setting. I think you can get around the "self-signed certificate" error by adding your CA using `git config --global http.https://your.site.here/.sslcainfo path.to.your.ca.cert` (works for me, anyway).

Comment: @CurtJSampson  The new error "self signed certificate..." occurred in Visual studio 2017 for me at the same time as the original error in question occurred in VsCode.  I was able to fixed the former error following this post: https://writeabout.net/2017/02/03/git-for-windows-with-tfs-and-ssl-behind-a-proxy/  though i am using git and Vsts.

Comment: @RMuesi The problem with that approach is that you don't get updated public CAs when _git_ updates, as you now have a custom `ca-bundle.crt` file. IMHO, it's better to simply use the `git config --global http.https://your.site.here/.sslcainfo path.to.your.ca.cert` option to tell _git_ the location of the CA certificate for the _git_ host using your self-signed/corporate certificate.

Comment: What worked for me was to completely delete (unset) the *http.sslCAInfo* property, as it overrides the default value (the windows certificate store)

Comment: If the problem is a self-signed or corporate certificate, then switching from SChannel to OpenSSL is not the solution. Instead, you may want to configure Windows to trust the certificate, or better, ask your system administrator to make it trusted on all machines in your organization, so you don't have to do rogue IT. This is also why you want to use SChannel.

Comment: @FlorianWinter: you can use self-signed and corporate certificates with OpenSSL. You don't have to use SChannel. Most users will have problems with SChannel, compared to using OpenSSL.

Comment: @MikeAllen I won't argue OpenSSL vs. SChannel (both have their benefits and people have their reasons to choose either), I only wanted to point out that proposing switching from SChannel to OpenSSL (or vice-versa) as the solution may be misleading, hiding the problem, or a step in the wrong direction.

Comment: @FlorianWinter I agree, I think that it should be possible to make either system work and that switching to a different TLS implementation doesn't have to be the answer.

Answer (score 9):

i got this error while working with vagrant(Installed Version: 2.2.16) on windows 10, caused by kaspersky anti-virus and got resolved when i added the sites vagrantcloud.com and cloud-images.ubuntu.com in trusted addressed for the antivirus to allow the encryted connections to be scanned and allowed as a trusted site. more information about antivirus setting changes can be found at https://support.kaspersky.com/KIS/2019/en-US/157530.htm

Fyi, The anti-virus softwares are known to cause such errors, all you need to do is to identify the site from where the download is taking place and add this to the trusted addresses for the antivirus program. in my case it was kaspersky anti virus. may be running the command using --debug to get the adjact site would be a good idea.

Comment: Thank you. That was a life saver. For CentOS box add `cloud.centos.org` to the list of trusted domains along with `vagrantcloud.com`

Answer (score 1):

Recently faced similar error with IntelliJ idea IDE and I was not able to pull code from git. it was throwing an error

**Unable to access :schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error (0x80092012) - The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate.**

I am able to pull code once I **added entry to windows credential manager** (check control panel) for git url and password for the git.

Comment: Just FYI : Using Windows 10 system