# The revocation function was unable to check revocation because the revocation server was offline

Tags: git, github

> fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab.com/********/******.git/':
>   schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error
>   (0x80092013) - The revocation function was unable to check revocation
>   because the revocation server was offline.

When trying to push my latest changes to GitLab from the GitHub desktop client I receive this error? I've never received this before and its always gone smoovly. When pushing after 1 week not committing its throwing this error?

I'm unsure how to fix this, it doesn't really give you much information.

Answer (score 11):

Using git version 2.24.0.windows.2, and this workaround is available:

```
git config --global http.schannelCheckRevoke false
```

From the [docs](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/blob/development/docs/known-issues.md#certificate-revocation-check-fails---3326):

> **We do not recommend setting this config value for normal Git usage.**
>   This is intended to be an "escape hatch" for situations where the
>   network administrator has restricted the normal usage of SChannel APIs
>   on Windows that Git is trying to use.

Answer (score 5):

Seems like a problem with your revocation server. Active Directory, may be?

Anyway [this bug](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/2414) suggests that [an option to turn revocation checking off](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/pull/1450) was merged and is available in git 2.16.1.windows.4.

```
git config --global http.schannelCheckRevoke false
```

Comment: The command is wrong. The correct syntax is in the answer above.

Comment: @DustWolf Yep, you're right. Fixed, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your PKI is misconfigured. You must make the CRL/OCSP service available to any client using your certificate.

1. Setup CRL and OCSP available for all clients.
2. Issue a new certificate using those.

It's best to just do it right from the beginning. I've setup many CA's and you can't miss the 1000's of lines of text about how you configure CRL and OCSP. Don't ignore them the next time.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking the firewall settings, in my case antivirus was blocking the connection between the server and client(windows machine).

Answer (score 0):

You can try resetting credentials in Windows to get a new prompt:
git config --unset-all credential.helper
The execute a "git push" command; it should bring up the authentication dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately disabling `http.schannelCheckRevoke` didn't work for me but switching git ssl backend to *OpenSSL* from *Windows Secure Channel library* worked really well. more details on this [SO answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46332681/14950385)

```bash
git config --global http.sslBackend openssl
```

Answer (score -1):

I fixed the issue manually deleting all expired certificates from my PC (certmgr.msc).
I read this in some forum and it worked however at this point I'm not sure why expired certificates cause this problem in some situations.