# 'curl' error is not allowing packages installation in RStudio under renv

Tags: r, curl

I recently upgraded R to 4.0.4 and RStudio to the latest version 1.4.1103.

Steps -

1. **Installing packages into system library** - Working fine
2. **Installing packages within an R Project** - Working fine
3. **Installing packages into an R Project within `renv`** - Unable to do so. I get the following error:

```
> install.packages("dplyr")
Error: package 'dplyr' is not available
In addition: Warning message:
curl: (35) schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error (0x80092012) - The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate.
```

My session info is given below:

> R version 4.0.4 (2021-02-15) Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
> Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18363)
>
> Matrix products: default
>
> locale: [1] LC_COLLATE=English_India.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_India.1252
> LC_MONETARY=English_India.1252 [4] LC_NUMERIC=C
> LC_TIME=English_India.1252
>
> attached base packages: [1] stats     graphics  grDevices datasets
> utils     methods   base
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached): [1] compiler_4.0.4
> tools_4.0.4    renv_0.12.5

I am wondering why this is happening. Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2):

I filed a bug report on your behalf here: https://github.com/rstudio/renv/issues/660

That said, this is most likely a duplicate of something like:

[curl: Unknown error (0x80092012) - The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54938026/curl-unknown-error-0x80092012-the-revocation-function-was-unable-to-check-r)

[The revocation function was unable to check revocation because the revocation server was offline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49082545/the-revocation-function-was-unable-to-check-revocation-because-the-revocation-se)

That is, something about how your system / network is configured is preventing `curl` from functioning normally.