# VS Code / Git error: "revocation server was offline" is not fixed by setting Git's http.schannelCheckRevoke to false

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

In VS Code, when I attempt to push changes I receive a "revocation server was offline" error exactly as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49082545/the-revocation-function-was-unable-to-check-revocation-because-the-revocation-se).

However, none of the suggested solutions have worked for me. I have set Git's `http.schannelCheckRevoke` to `false` on both a local and global level.

This problem only happens in VS Code. On the command line Git works normally.

Any idea why this could be limited to VS Code?