# VS 2019 Git timeout connecting to bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket, visual-studio-2019

I have a brand new install of Visual Studio 2019 (version 16.2.5) Community Edition. I've selected git for source control and installed the Bitbucket extension (through which I can log in just fine.) However, whenever I try to clone or pull an existing repo I get the following error (without ever being prompted for credentials):

"Git failed with a fatal error. Unable to access '[my repo]': Failed to connect to bitbucket.org on port 443: Timed out."

I also get the error when I try to clone using Git for Windows. My VS 2015 CE still seems able to interact with Bitbucket just fine.

Googling this issue I can't find much referencing VS2019, although there's plenty for VS2017. I've tried the first and third solutions in this (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/4833/git-failed-with-a-fatal-error.html) (although not the second as it's a timeout error, not SSL related.) I've also tried removing all Bitbucket related credentials from Credential Manager.

The only other clue I can see is that if I try to update the git global settings in VS it does not pick anything up from the gitconfig file in my user directory and trying to save changes causes it to complain permission was denied on 'C:\windows\system32.gitconfig'. I have no idea why it would expect there to be a config file here.

Any ideas gratefully received!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ***IS*** a proxy/SSL issue!

I followed [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/comments/260621/view.html) advice to enable git trace logging and identified where git was running from, and its associated gitconfig file. I updated this file to point to our proxy and *lo*, we start to get different error messages.

**However.** We use corporate self-signed certificates, and if I set git to use schannel (`http.sslBackend = schannel`) then I get this error:

> schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error
>   (0x80092012) - The revocation function was unable to check revocation
>   for the certificate.

If set it to `openssl` I get this:

> SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

More googling. Apparently the recommended approach is to use openssl and export your cert to the local store. Which would be fine for me, but I need this tooling to be adopted by the rest of the team. So I took the approach recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53090169/4278585), and added `http.schannelcheckrevoke = false` to the config (see the linked SO response for an explanation of the security trade-offs, which seem to be OK if you're behind a proxy.)

By this point I had versions of git and gitconfig files all over the shop, so a bit of a cleanup was necessary. I followed [this advice](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Could-not-read-Password-for-https-xxxxx-bitbucket-org-terminal/qaq-p/874695) to get VS to use the latest version of Git for Windows, and, once it was I was able to use the git command prompt and `git config --list --show-origin` to determine what config was being picked up and from where.

Once this was done I was successfully able to clone my repo in VS2019.