# Revocation certificate error when trying to pull GIT repo

Tags: git, certificate, schannel

I know there are a few similar posts to this but I have not been able to solve this with there answers.

I tried `git config —global http.schannelcheckrevoke false` but I still get the error whether it’s set to true or false.

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/***/***/': schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error (0x80092012) - The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate.
```

Shouldn't setting http.schannelcheckrevoke to false prevent this error? What am I missing here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git - The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45556189/git-the-revocation-function-was-unable-to-check-revocation-for-the-certificate)

Comment: The first answer to that post is the one that I am attempting but it doesn't change anything oddly.

Answer (score -2):

there is a problem in your connection so focus on that . I used VPN for connection and it solved as easy as piece of cake :)