# How to import a zscaler certificate into Git

Tags: git, ssl, azure-devops, ssl-certificate, zscaler

While trying to checkin/checkout code on azure DevOps from GIT i got the following error.

[image: SSL certificate Error]

Application has to send the traffic to Zscaler proxies. For this we have un-set the proxy in GIT post that application able to connect URL but SSL handshake was not happening. 
GIT is not aware of Zscaler certificate due to which it could not establish SSL handshake with destination server.
I need to find a way to Import Zscaler certificate in GIT application so that it can connect the destination.
Is it possible to just copy paste the certificate into GIT folder.
What are the certificate under Git\usr\ssl\certs
Can someone please assist.

Comment: Have a look at git `http.sslCAInfo` configuration option and see this case as an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16543283/6368697

Comment: same problem here, any progress since October?

Comment: @fontophilic check my answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I configure Git to trust certificates from the Windows Certificate Store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16668508/how-do-i-configure-git-to-trust-certificates-from-the-windows-certificate-store)

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Was able to bypass this issue with the command, however poses a security risk

> `git config --global http.sslVerify false`

To trust a certificate, you can try these steps and check the result:

1. Export the certificate through browser (e.g. chrome): Click lock
   icon in address bar > Certificate > Certification Path > Select
   top-most certificate in the chain > View Certificate > Copy to file
   (Choose Base-64 encoded X.509).
2. Copy content to ca-bundle.crt file
   (check http.sslcainfo value by calling git config –l command) More
   information: Adding a corporate (or self-signed) certificate
   authority to git.exe’s store

[More information: Adding a corporate (or self-signed) certificate authority to git.exe’s store](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/phkelley/2014/01/20/adding-a-corporate-or-self-signed-certificate-authority-to-git-exes-store/)

Comment: Please don't recommend/show disabling ALL GIT CERTIFICATE VALIDATION without a disclaimer that this can be a significant security issue. For your scenario (corporate/zscaler/ssl inspection) please look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48212753/468244).

Comment: @SimonOpelt that's a perfect answer!

Comment: @KimballRobinson it is actually not a perfect answer. The bypass setting allows you to use any git repo out there, without a (or maybe a invalid) certificate. Which allows a man in the middle attack, which introduces other issues more worse than a failing git connection.

Salman, adding the trust (if one is really trusting the certificate) is a valid answer, but is completely useless with the bypass mentioned. Therefore -1.

Answer (score 4):

For a corporate scenario (zscaler, ssl inspection ...) switching from OpenSSL to the Windows implementation of SSL/certificate validation (SCHANNEL) might be a good option. It ensures that git will be using the same certificate store as many other apps you are using. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48212753/468244) discusses the required setting.

Compared to solutions like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/phkelley/adding-a-corporate-or-self-signed-certificate-authority-to-git-exes-store), the approach avoids having to update the certificates stored specifically for git if IT needs to roll out updates.

Comment: thank you, the answer in the link (`git config --global http.sslBackend schannel`) solved our issue with Zscaler.

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. The other is just wrong. Wrong because use of SSL/TLS is IMPLICIT in the quesiton. Disabling it is problematic.