# Error entering "$ git push -u origin main " gets SSL certificate problem

Tags: git, ssl, github, git-bash

I am learning how to use GitHub. For this I needed Git. I don't know how to use Git, I am just following the tutorial for GitHub.

When I enter `$ git push -u origin main` , I get `fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/xxx/github-upload.git/': SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate` (replaced username with "xxx"). I do not know what this means or what to do about it (besides the obvious that I am having SSL certificate issues, but I did not touch SSL, and am not experiencing issues anywhere else).

I have tried searching online and on forums that might be able to help understand and fix what is wrong, but I can find no documentation.

I am using Git Bash.

Comment: Are you able to access the URL from the error message in a browser from the same computer? Have you ever been able to push or pull from that machine to that repo or any other repo?

Comment: @TheIceBear I can access it in the browser. Its my first time, so I have never pushed or pulled to a repo.

Comment: What version of git do you have? There are similar questions, like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/53064542/761202 ( do not blindly disable certificate checks as some answers advocate!)

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48212753/5024726