# Visual Studio code not asking me for git credentials, and instead says 'SSL certificate problem'

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, bitbucket

I am trying to run the following command

```
git pull
```

I receive the following message

```
fatal: unable to access '<bitbucket repository URL>': SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
```

It *SHOULD* be asking me for my credentials (e.g. username and password) before I can push or pull. Why is it not asking me for them (as previously, it would prompt me before i could push or pull?).

I do NOT want to try and bypass this problem by disabling SSL verification (due to security concerns).

I have already tried removing the credential from Windows credential manager (it didn't help).

How do I get VS Code to ask me for my bitbucket credentials when doing a git pull?

I get the same behavior occurring when I do this in windows CMD prompt as well.

Comment: It is not asking you credentials because the check of the ssl certificate is done first. Does this solution solve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/a/48212753/717372

Answer (score 1):

Can you please check if the remote url of your repository with command:

```
git remote -v
```

If it starts with ssh, you may want to update it to a https version with command and see if it resolves the problem:

```
git remote set-url origin git@bitbucket.org:[your_repo_address]
```

Here is a detail page of how to do it under bitbucket:
https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/change-the-remote-url-to-your-repository/

You can also check bitbucket knowledge base for another possible solution:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/resolving-ssl-self-signed-certificate-errors-806029899.html

Comment: After running git remote -v I can see my two https repos are connected; however I still get the SSL certificate problem. I tried it as SSH but still didn't work