# git clone https/ssl error

Tags: git, ssl, https

I have installed the ssl certificate and key in my git server. But am getting error when i try to clone via https from my mysysgit. Earlier it was working fine with http. Unable to identify where it is failing

```
$ git clone https://server.name/git/testing.git
Cloning into 'testing'...
* Couldn't find host server.name in the _netrc file; using defaults
* About to connect() to server.name port 443 (#0)
*   Trying server.name...
* Adding handle: conn: 0x274fd60
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x274fd60) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* Connected to server.name(server.name) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Git/bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate
* Closing connection 0
fatal: unable to access 'https://server.name/git/testing.git/': SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate
```

Comment: This has been marked as duplicate of the question relating to self-signed certificates. However, this can happen also with non self-signed certificates when an intermediate certificate is not registered on the server.

Please, see: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=787281

The explanation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#chains

And the possible solution (with nginx): https://futurestud.io/tutorials/how-to-configure-nginx-ssl-certifcate-chain

Answer (score 82):

If you are getting an error while doing a `git clone`, then above needs to be changed to:

```
git config --global http.sslVerify false
```

Comment: You should probably never do this globally like this. Do it on a per repo basis without the `--global`.

Comment: Agreed Travis the --global poses a significant security risk.

Comment: See the other question/answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621768/how-can-i-make-git-accept-a-self-signed-certificate for how to do this on a per-command basis: `git -c http.sslVerify=false clone . . .`

Comment: Works for: `fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/somerepo.git/': Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)` 
`

Answer (score 24):

You might have to disable the certificate verification in your case:

```
cd /path/to/repo
git config http.sslVerify false
```

(as in "[Git: ignore a self signed certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11622001/6309)")

The other option, similar to "[Unable to clone Git repository due to self signed certificate](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/FISHKB/Unable+to+clone+Git+repository+due+to+self+signed+certificate)" would be to import that certificate into git.

That is: copied it at the end of the file `/path/to/git/bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt`.

I would not advise `git config --global http.sslVerify false`, as that would disable certificate verification for *all* local repositories.

Comment: I got  => fatal: not in a git directory. What does meaning ?

Comment: @Aguid It means you have not executed that command in a local git repository (a folder with a .`git` subfolder in it)

Comment: @Aguid True, but not recommended. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 4):

Check your .gitconfig file.

If you've found the following line, Remove it!

```
[http]
sslCAinfo = /bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt
```

It worked for me.