# SSL certificate generated with OpenSSL not working on NSS

Tags: curl, ssl, openssl, certificate, nss

I have SSL certificate ( key.pem, cacert.pem, pcert.pem ) generated with OpenSSL on Linux Mint machine. Now I'm trying to move my application to another server where is installed Fedora 18 with NSS.

cURL is returning this error:

```
unable to load client key: -8178 (SEC_ERROR_BAD_KEY)
```

I tested again and on my computer is working fine but on server not. I think it's because I used OpenSSL to generate certificates but on server is installed NSS.

I can't find how to generate certificates with "certutil" or with "openssl" to be valid with NSS.

Comment: How do you generate your certificates with openssl?

Comment: And what does your key file start with? I mean `-----BEGIN WHAT-----`.

Comment: I generate with: openssl pkcs12 -in YOURPFX.pfx -nocerts -out key.pem    
openssl pkcs12 -in YOURPFX.pfx -clcerts -nokeys -out pcert.pem  

openssl pkcs12 -in YOURPFX.pfx -cacerts -nokeys -out cacert.pem

Comment: My certificate starts with: -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

Comment: What about the private key?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The failure was due to my PKCS#8 private key format:
 - With a PKCS#8 private key
       `-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----` header
   or
       `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----` header
   curl+openssl works, but not curl+nss+libnsspem.so
 - With a RSA private key
       `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` header
   both curl+openssl and curl+nss+libnsspem.so work.

So use this command `openssl rsa -in key.pem -out newkey.pem` to remove the pass phrase on an RSA private key:

Comment: If you don't want to remove passphrase from your key, just use another encryption algorythm, that `curl+nss` will successfully understand. Use `openssl rsa -des3 -in your.key -out your.encrypted.key` to reencrypt it.

Comment: @cronfy, des3 is the only cipher that curl+nss seems to accept on Centos 7.4. Any ideas what's up with that?

Comment: Apparently this is a known bug, reported in 2016. nss-pem does not support keys that use encryption other than des. -- https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1369251