# SSL error while cloning from github enterprise on AWS EC2 instance

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, github-enterprise

My ultimate goal is to be able to do pip installs from our github enterprise server using the Elastic Beanstalk. The issue is that the ec2 instances will not trust our SSL certificate from Network Solutions.

Traceback from an Elastic Beanstalk Python EC2 instance:

```
>> git clone https://my.ghe.com/some/repo.git
Cloning into 'squire'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://my.ghe.com/some/repo.git/': Peer's Certificate issuer is not recognized.
```

I've tried a half-dozen possible fixes to no avail. Has anyone had any success cloning over https? I'd like to avoid cloning over ssh so I don't have to deal with the ssh keys in eb.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this answer about using `git config` to disable SSL verification and other SSL-overriding options:

[How can I make git accept a self signed certificate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621768/how-can-i-make-git-accept-a-self-signed-certificate)