# git clone using GitPython library

Tags: ssl, gitpython

How to clone with disabled SSL checking, using GitPython library. The following code ...

```
import git
x = git.Repo.clone_from('https://xxx', '/home/xxx/lala')
```

... yields this error:

```
Error: fatal: unable to access 'xxx': server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
```

I know about "export GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=1", but how to implement it in a python library ?

Answer (score 6):

The two following methods have been tested with GitPython 2.0.8 but should be working at least since 1.0.2 (from the doc).

As suggested by @Byron:

```py
git.Repo.clone_from(
  'https://example.net/path/to/repo.git',
  'local_destination',
  branch='master', depth=1,
  env={'GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY': '1'},
)
```

As suggested by [@Christopher](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11622001/248390):

```py
git.Repo.clone_from(
  'https://example.net/path/to/repo.git',
  'local_destination',
  branch='master', depth=1,
  config='http.sslVerify=false',
)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems easiest to pass the `GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY` environment variable to all git invocations. Unfortunately [`Git.update_environment(...)`](http://gitpython.readthedocs.org/en/stable/reference.html?highlight=update_environment#git.cmd.Git.update_environment) can only be used on an existing instance, which is why you would have to manipulate python's environment like so:

```
import git
import os

os.environ['GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY'] = "1"
repo = git.Repo.clone_from('https://xxx', '/home/xxx/lala')
```