# Https certificate errors for GitHub using git on Windows 7

Tags: git, github, digital-certificate

Currently, I get this error:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/square/haha.git
Cloning into 'haha'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/square/haha.git/': SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
```

I am on a Windows 7 machine. I've learned that Github's certificate is signed by DigiCert. If I look in *Trusted Root Certification Authorities > Certificates*, I see certificates Issued To DigiCert:

```
DigiCert Assured ID Root CA
DigiCert Assured ID Root G2
DigiCert Assured ID Root G3
DigiCert Global Root CA
DigiCert Global Root G2
DigiCert Global Root G3
DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA
DigiCert Trusted Root G4
```

Is the GitHub certificate contained within one of these?
If so, how do I use it? If not how do I get it?

Edit - more info:
I can set sslVerify to false and it works, but this is not secure of course.
I can use git:// instead of https://. This also works, but is not https.

I CANNOT USE SSH as this environment does not have proxies set up.
Using ssh:

```
    $ git clone ssh://github.com/square/haha.git
    Cloning into 'haha'...
    D:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
    D:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/bash: -c: line 0: `exec corkscrew <proxyhost> <proxyport> ssh.github.com 443 ~/.ssh/proxy_auth'
    write: Broken pipe
    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: Can you go to https://github.com in a browser?

Comment: Yes. I can also set sslVerify to false and get the repository.

Comment: Can you clone via ssh?

Comment: Assuming that would mean replacing https with ssh, just tried it on your suggestion. See edit to question.

Comment: you should submit your key to server before cloning via ssh, command will look like this `git clone git@github.com:square/haha.git`

Comment: Your `ssh` configuration is broken.  Remove the ProxyCommand from your `ssh_config`.

Comment: @LongDương: Executing that command gives the same result as with ssh (unexpected token < ...)

Comment: @larsks: ssh_config or sshd_config do not contain any such line. I even did a search on all files in *D:\Program Files\Git* for `<proxyhost>` and found nothing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The idea is to download the self-signed certificate, and reference it during the clone:

```
git -c http.sslCAInfo=/path/to/self/signed/cert clone https://github.com/square/haha.git
```

For instance, you can use [`iwonbigbro/tools/bin/git-remote-install-cert.sh`](https://github.com/iwonbigbro/tools/blob/master/bin/git-remote-install-cert.sh) to:

- download said certificates (including the self-signed one)

  ```
  openssl s_client -connect
  ```
- register that certificate:

  ```
  git config --global http.sslCAPath "$HOME/.gitcerts"
  ```

(here `$HOME/.gitcerts` is a directory in which all certificates can be found by git)

That tool, since it is called `git-remote-install-cert.sh`, is executed by a `git remote-install-cert` (even on Windows).

I would recommend though to use the latest [`PortableGit-2.5.1-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.5.1.windows.1/PortableGit-2.5.1-64-bit.7z.exe), uncompressed anywhere (like in `C:\prgs\PortableGit-2.5.1-64-bit`).
Then call `C:\prgs\PortableGit-2.5.1-64-bit\git-bash.exe`, check `$PATH` and try `git remote-install-cert`.

---

Example, in a simple DOS session, with a `PATH` including `C:\prgs\bin`:
(it also include `C:\prgs\PortableGit-2.5.1-64-bit\bin`, which means I am using git 2.5.0 here)

- create a file `C:\prgs\bin\git-remote-install-cert` in which you copy [`iwonbigbro/tools/bin/git-remote-install-cert.sh`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/iwonbigbro/tools/master/bin/git-remote-install-cert.sh) (so no trailing `.sh` in the final local script file name)
- Change the line 111 from `mkdir -m 0700 -p ${cert%/*}`  to `mkdir -p ${cert%/*}` (no need to change the line 37 though)
- Go into an existing repo.
  Or create one, and add the remote origin url:
  (Of course, adapt the path to your environment)

  ```
  cd C:\Users\vonc\prog
  git init b2d
  cd b2d
  git remote add origin https://github.com/VonC/b2d
  ```
- Finally, call the script from that repo

  ```
  C:\Users\vonc\prog\b2d>git remote-install-cert
    Requesting certificate from the server...
    Certificate installed to: /c/Users/vonc/.gitcerts/github.com.crt
  ```

That will give you the certificates:

```
C:\Users\vonc\prog\b2d>type C:\Users\vonc\.gitcerts\github.com.crt
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIF4DCCBMigAwIBAgIQDACTENIG2+M3VTWAEY3chzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADB1
MQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEVMBMGA1UEChMMRGlnaUNlcnQgSW5jMRkwFwYDVQQLExB3
d3cuZGlnaWNlcnQuY29tMTQwMgYDVQQDEytEaWdpQ2VydCBTSEEyIEV4dGVuZGVk
IFZhbGlkYXRpb24gU2VydmVyIENBMB4XDTE0MDQwODAwMDAwMFoXDTE2MDQxMjEy
MDAwMFowgfAxHTAbBgNVBA8MFFByaXZhdGUgT3JnYW5pemF0aW9uMRMwEQYLKwYB
BAGCNzwCAQMTAlVTMRkwFwYLKwYBBAGCNzwCAQITCERlbGF3YXJlMRAwDgYDVQQF
Ewc1MTU3NTUwMRcwFQYDVQQJEw41NDggNHRoIFN0cmVldDEOMAwGA1UEERMFOTQx
....
```

From there, you can, still in that repo, fetch using that certificate:

```
cd C:\Users\vonc\prog\b2d
git config http.sslcapath C:\Users\vonc\.gitcerts
git fetch
git checkout master
```

Comment: Entering `openssl s_client -connect` results in *usage: s_client args*

Comment: @AlLelopath this was just an extract of the script, illustrating the command which will extract the certificate, but you still have to execute the script, not that single command.

Comment: Yes, my mistake. When I execute the script I get *syntax error near unexpected token "<"*, line 37 `done < <(git remote -v)`

Comment: @AlLelopath Please replace the second `<` by a `$`: `done < $(git remote -v)`

Comment: The command for windows is `sh git-remote-install-cert.sh`. Doing that, I now get *fatal: Not a git repository(or any of the parent directories): .git \n line 29: $(git-remote -v): ambigous redirect\n Remote origin not found*

Comment: Not sh ..., but, as I explained in the answer: `git remote-install-cert`

Comment: Not to be contrary, but that doesn't work. `sh git-remote-install-cert.sh` executes the script, and then I get the errors mentioned above.

Comment: @AlLelopath rename `git-remote-install-cert.sh` as `git-remote-install-cert` (no trailing `.sh` here), make sure it is in one of the folder referenced by `%PATH%`, and type `git remote-install-cert` (no trailing `.sh` there). Any script named `git-xxx` allows to be called by `git xxx`. The interest? Using a shell script from a Windows session, because `git-xxx` will be executed within a msys git shell session through `git xxx`.

Comment: I have now renamed the file to `git-remote-install-cert`. I have moved it to `/c/Users/allelopath/bin` which is a directory on PATH. Then typing `git remote-install-cert` results in the *not a git repository* and *remote origin not found* errors mentioned above

Comment: @AlLelopath the script expect to be in a git repo. Create one (`git init test`; `cd test`; `git remote add origin https://github.com/square/haha.git`), then call `git remote-install-cert` from that same test folder.

Comment: Following your instructions, I now have */c/Users/allelopath/test*. I added this directory to the PATH. This directory has a *.git* directory and the file `git-remote-install-cert`. Executing the script still gets errors, the *line 29 ... ambigous redirect* and the *Remote origin not found*

Comment: Do not put the script there, I never said anything about moving the script in the Git repo.

Comment: @AlLelopath I just added (and just tested) a step-by-step procedure for you to follow. See my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks for this. I get to the step of `git remote add origin ...` with no trouble, but when I do `git remote-install-cert`, I get nothing in response. It pauses for just a second, and then returns to the prompt. The directory of this file is on the PATH. I tried adding echo/printf statements to the script, but I still see nothing. How would I call it with the usage parameter just to see if I'm talking to it?

Comment: Do you have a file named `git-remote-install-cert` in that PATH? When you type git --version, do you see 2.5.x?

Comment: I have the file `D:\prgs\bin\git-remote-install-cert`. The path has `/d/prgs/bin`.Git version is *2.5.0.windows.1*

Comment: @AlLelopath Can you try from a simple DOS session, with a `%PATH%` referencing the git 2.5, and `D:\prgs\bin`?

Comment: I added D:\Program Files\Git\bin and D:\prgs\bin to the PATH in the Environment Variables tool, Then from a DOS session, I did `git remote-install-cert" and the behavior is the same. A pause for just a second, and then back to the prompt.

Comment: @AlLelopath Is there anything else in your `%PATH%` (beside the mandatory `C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOW\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\`) that might interfere with git?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "interfere with git", since a 'git --version' returns 2.5.0.windows.1. There are 2 other git.exe files, both under the same installation, in D:\Program Files\Git\mingw64 and D:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec, but these directories are not on the path.

Comment: @AlLelopath please type `set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOW\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wind‌​owsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\path\to\git2.5.0\bin;D:\prgs\bin`, and try again. The idea is to have a minimal PATH, with only the required programs in it.

Comment: Just did as you said. Version is still 2.5.0.windows.0. Response is still the same (small pause, then back to prompt)

Comment: @AlLelopath Do you have a Windows 7/8 64 bits, with the Git 2.5 64bits on it?

Comment: Yes, Windows 7 64 bit. Downloaded Git-2.5.0-64-bit.exe about a week ago.

Comment: @AlLelopath Then try and don't use the .exe setup, but only the https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.5.1.windows.1/PortableGit-2.5.1-64-bit.7z.exe auto-extractible archive. uncompress it in a `D:\prgs\PortableGit-2.5.1-64-bit` folder, and add `D:\prgs\PortableGit-2.5.1-64-bit\bin` to your `%PATH%`.

Comment: Did as instructed. Version is changed to 2.5.1.windows.1. Response is still the same.

Comment: @AlLelopath Can you try on another Windows 7 or 8 machine? I tested it on multiple machine without any issue.

Comment: That will take more doing, if at all possible. Will get back to you.

Comment: Hi, I will not be able to get to  another machine anytime soon. You have gone above and beyond the call of duty. Thank you.

Comment: @AlLelopath Let me know if you are able to make it work in the end.

Comment: I have a self signed cert which I generated with openssl on a windows machine but I am not sure how to use that cert while doing a `git fetch`. Looking for help

Comment: @FakharAhmadRasul Did you try the `git -c http.sslCAInfo=/path/to/self/signed/cert fetch` command, with the config mentioned at the beginning of this answer? For testing?

Comment: @VonC Yes I did, I see a warning saying `TLS certificate verification has been disabled!` and `git fetch` does not do anything

Comment: @Fak ok, could you ask a separate question in order to put more details about your issue?

Comment: Here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67577435/tls-certificate-verification-has-been-disabled-while-trying-to-git-fetch

Answer (score -3):

try

```
git -c http.sslVerify=false clone https://github.com/square/haha.git
```

or execute `git config --global http.sslVerify false` and clone again

Comment: I didn't downvote this, but I think that the reason for it is that I mentioned that I have already tried setting sslVerify to false.

Comment: i see, do you try with `--global` flag?