# ssl virfication failed though i have disabled it

Tags: git

I set `sslVerify` to `false` using the following command but I still get verification error when I try to clone remote repository:

```
sudo git config --global http.sslVerfiy false
```

Here is the error:

```
fatal: unable to access 'xxx': server certificate verification failed.
CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
```

It worked before I upgrade to ubuntu 14.04!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem resolved by adding sslVerify=false to the clone command:

```
git -c http.sslVerify=false clone xxx
```

[Thanks for this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11622001)