# Git Integration in RadStudio / Delphi 10

Tags: git, delphi, bitbucket-server

I setup a [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/) server on a 2012r2 VM.

I can successfully clone, push, commit from the Git command line.

After reading [this blogpost written by Luis Navarro](https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/version-control-get-started-with-git-remote-repositories-and-rad-studio-xe8) (Embarcadero), I thought this was going to be an easy setup.

However, whenever I try to clone a project, I get the following error message:

[image: error]

The weird thing is I chose to access **http**://MYURL.org/scm/waaad/vcl.git but it automatically changed to **https** instead.

Also, when I try use SSH instead, the error stays the same but gets displayed in a MessageBox instead:

[image: error]

Grabbing sources from e.g. https://github.com/project-jedi/jvcl.git works fine.

Has anyone with a local installation of a Git repository encountered the same problems?

Are there any alternative Git implementations other then the default one by Embarcadero?

**Edit:**

Based on Rob Kennedy's comment i changed the Git-Option exectuable to:

[image]

The SSL-error is gone now but it still can't clone because:

[image]

Is there any way to stop it automatically changing the **http to https**?
I think thats the reason it can't locate the repository.

Comment: Presumably, grabbing code from GitHub works fine because GitHub's certificate looks legit, whereas yours doesn't. Can you [configure git to accept your self-signed certificate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11621768/33732)?

Comment: I don't have a certificate and i use http intead of https. I am not sure what certificate RadStudio expects and why it changes my http clone request to https.

Comment: IDE integration is over rated. Especially when it is poorly implemented and limited in scope.  Use a different tool for your revision control.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I don't think IDE integration is over rated. It's convenient to have access to your version control with the tool you are developing with. I agree that the implementation is bad and needs improvment.

Comment: It would be convenient if it were functional. It isn't.

Comment: Pardon the obvious question, but don't BitBucket's vendors have anything to say about this problem?

Comment: @MartynA https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/securing-bitbucket-server-with-apache-using-ssl-776640117.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the official documentation:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/securing-bitbucket-server-with-apache-using-ssl-776640117.html

> You can run Bitbucket Server behind a reverse proxy, such as Apache
>   HTTP Server or nginx, that is secured using HTTPS (HTTP over SSL). You
>   should consider doing this, and making secure access mandatory, if
>   usernames, passwords and other proprietary data may be at risk.

---

My initial answer (actually saying the same):

If no better solution comes up, I would install Apache or nginx on the Git server and configure it as a reverse HTTPS proxy.

Example configuration: https://serverfault.com/questions/486042/use-apache-as-a-https-to-http-proxy

RAD Studio then should happily be using HTTPS. The Apache Server communicates with Git over HTTP. Both sides happy :)

Comment: Following the official guide got it working. Thanks for the link :)