# Android Studio to BitBucket push error - self signed certificate in certificate chain

Tags: git, android-studio, bitbucket

I've just started using Android Studio (v1.5.1 for Windows 7) and I want to be able to use BitBucket over HTTPS with it (I have Git v2.7.1.0 installed).
I have followed instructions on how to set it up from [here](http://myviewonsoftwaredevelopment.blogspot.co.uk/2016/02/quickly-setup-android-studio-with-git.html), which all seemed very straightforward.

However, when it comes to pushing my project to BitBucket it always fails with a "Push failed" error, the latest one being
**fatal: unable to access 'https://*USERNAME*@bitbucket.org/*USERNAME*/*MYPROJECT*.git/': SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain**

The self signed certificate (selfcert.cer) was created from my browser while on BitBucket's website, which I read somewhere I had to do.

This is all new to me so I'm not really sure what to try next.

Answer (score 7):

Self signed certificate  could be accepted running following command in command line

```
> git config http.sslVerify false
```

other git command should work after this.

This should be just temporary solution as it has security implications.
Proper way to fix this is to import certificate. Detail here on https://confluence.atlassian.com/fishkb/unable-to-clone-git-repository-due-to-self-signed-certificate-376838977.html or refer [How can I make git accept a self signed certificate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621768/how-can-i-make-git-accept-a-self-signed-certificate/26785963)