# Git Plugin for Jenkins Fails to Connect to Repository

Tags: git, jenkins, ubuntu-14.04

I am setting up a Jenkins master/slave configuration. I have the slave setup and connected to the master. I am having some trouble with connecting to my SCM which is on Git.

I am getting the following error:
[image]

I have made certain on the master that the Git path is defined correctly. I have also looked at other similar questions and none have helped as they all revolve around SSH keys. We are not using SSH keys, I am simply using my Git user name and password which has worked on other setups I have done recently. I also set on the node properties a tool location for Git for the slave.

Is there anything I need to do on the slave that I am missing? How do I resolve this? By the way, the master and slave are both Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: That error seems pretty clear: "server certificate verification failed".  The plugin is unable to verify the SSL certificate used by the remote server.  Your choices are (a) install the correct CA certificates in `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`, or (b) see if there is a mechanism available by which you can disable certificate verification.  Obviously (a) is a much better solution.

Comment: So how do I do option A? Follow-on question, where would I get one?

Comment: Another follow-on question, why haven't I had to do this with any other Jenkins setup? Windows or CentOS, the connection just worked.

Comment: Maybe just a different set of default CA certificates available on the local system?  In any case, how to find/install the appropriate ca certificate is probably a different question, and there are lots of resources out there that cover the topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the way that I solved this was by dumping Ubuntu and going to CentOS. Worked just fine right out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

Your server's SSL certificate cannot be verified by the GIT client.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11622001/4494577) is an SO answer on how to deal with this. In short you'll have to make the cert known to GIT.

EDIT: Please don't disable SSL cert validation. This is not the right choice and strips SSL of its main purpose.

Comment: Sorry after reading that I am still completely lost. Why is this needed? I have setup other Jenkins servers without having to do this? Also the answer in the link didn't really have any answers that worked for me. I tried `git -c http.sslVerify=false` and `GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=true` in my shell script in Jenkins and neither worked. Also what cert?