# Try to install the Laravel 5.5. It's showing the OpenSSL certificate error

Tags: php, laravel

I am new from laravel. I am using windows10. PHP v7.0.10 (wamp)
I have installed the composer.

I have tried to install the laravel using the command (composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog)

It's showing the error. I have attached the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621768/how-can-i-make-git-accept-a-self-signed-certificate

Comment: Do you have git installed on your system?

Comment: @HalfCrazed Thanks for your reply. I will make a new project. But this project I will not use the git.

Comment: @boopathi008 composer is trying to install dependencies via git, fyi.

Comment: @Camilo Thanks for your reply. I have installed the git in my system

Comment: @HalfCrazed I have tried **git config http.sslVerify false** this command. It's working fine. Thanks