# installation of Git for Windows failing in certificate error

Tags: git

I'm trying to install Git on Windows10 but cannot get over a certificate error.The error event in command prompt is as follows.

```
git clone http://-----.git
cloning into '-----'
fatal:UriFormatException encountered
  queryURL
Password for '[proxy]':
fatal:unable to access 'https://----git':error setting certificate verify location
CAfile C:\XX\YY\ZZ\ca-bundle.crt
CApath:none
```

`ca-bundle.crt` is in `C:\XX\ZZ` directory, not in the directory above.
Surprising was that neither  `git config --global http.sslcainfo "C:\XX\ZZ\ca-bundle.crt"` nor `git config --global http.sslVerify false` did change any result although gitconfig file was successfully rewritten.
Is there any suggestion or information for help?

additional
`git config --global --edit` shows now

```
 [http]
  proxy=------
  sslCAinfo=----
```

but `git clone` command bring me to the same error.

Comment: Did you actully try http.sslCAInfo or sslcainfo? maybe you typed it wrong?

Comment: tried both. I didn't know that there were 3 config files. I edited my question. I don't want to disable the ssl certificate mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the answer over [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19363404/4191196)

You can set `GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY` to `true`:

```bash
GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=true git clone https://example.com/path/to/git
```

or alternatively configure Git not to verify the connection on the command line:

```bash
git -c http.sslVerify=false clone https://example.com/path/to/git
```

Note that if you don't verify SSL/TLS certificates, then **you are susceptible to MitM attacks**.