# SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea

I have upgraded my Inteliij IDEA 2019.2 recently and I am getting the following error if I try to pull from using my IDE:

> Git Pull Failed: unable to access 'https://github.xxx.com/app-Hello-USD/DGS.git/': SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain.

Could someone help me what option I have to enable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make git accept a self signed certificate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621768/how-can-i-make-git-accept-a-self-signed-certificate)

Answer (score 96):

`git config --global http.sslVerify false`

Comment: Could you please explain why this is happening?

Comment: @Meredith Usually it's a content filter/proxy/firewall that filters the SSL traffic in your network and uses the self signed certificate in order to decrypt all the secure traffic. Contact your network administrator / IT Helpdesk / Security team for details. Another possible case is when the git repository is configured with the self signed certificate.  Contact the git server administrator for more details.

Comment: not a good solution, better solution would be to add the self-signed certificate to the trusted certificates

Comment: @ErdincAy can you please explain how to do it?

Comment: @AhinoamMazuz look up the JDK - Folder of your system / your environment, that you use (for Maven or your IDE), you'll find an JRE folder in there, go down to libs and then to security, there you'll find the cacerts - Certificate Store file .... for example: C:/jdk1.8.0_202/jre/lib/security/cacerts ... now use KeyStore Explorer http://keystore-explorer.org/ and add the certificate that is missing (the Java Certificate Store Default Passwort is: changeit)

Comment: Don't forget to enable SSL verification after you've cloned the repository, otherwise Git will refuse to use SSL for any repository.

Comment: I _really_ wish "reduce security by breaking SSL certificate trust" wasn't the top answer to this question.

Answer (score 71):

We can use Windows certificate storage mechanism.

Please try this

```
git config --global http.sslbackend schannel
```

Comment: This is probably the best answer. That way we can import certs using Windows's native tools and not break basic functionality.

Comment: I'm commenting to bring more attention to this answer. For Windows, this is the best answer.   Especially if you are using a company owned and managed computer. When the company pushes updates to the CA it won't break your environment if you use schannel. Folks who work at a company where they unwrap and rewrap ssl traffic know what I mean.

Comment: The best answer for windows. Thanks.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Disabline SSL verification is a workaround suitable for diagnostics, but in a well configured Windows dev environment, Git really ought to be using the Windows cert management functionality.

Comment: Why does this work?

Comment: Best answer for Windows. Worked for me, on Windows 10.

Comment: Worked for me on Windows 11 Enterprise in the terminal. Git does still not work inside VS Code due to SSL errors.

Answer (score 39):

This usually happens when your Git repository server is hosted inside a private network and uses a locally generated (self signed) TLS certificate. Because this certificate is not from a "trusted" source, most software will complain that the connection is not secure.

There's two ways to go about solving this. First is to disable SSL verification so you can clone the repository. Second is to add the self-signed certificate to Git as a trusted certificate.

## Disable SSL Verification

The quickest and easiest way is to globally disable SSL verification on Git to clone the repository. But after cloning, you will immediately enable it again, otherwise Git won't verify certificate signatures for other repositories.

1. Disable SSL verification on Git globally:

   ```
   git config --global http.sslVerify false
   ```
2. Clone your repository:

   ```
   git clone <your repo>
   ```
3. Enable SSL verification on Git globally:

   ```
   git config --global http.sslVerify true
   ```
4. Change directory into your repo:

   ```
   cd <your repo>
   ```
5. Disable SSL verification only on your repository:

   ```
   git config --local http.sslVerify false
   ```

This is the easiest solution to implement, however you are skipping a SSL verification for specific repositories, and Git will constantly show security warning messages:

```
warning: ----------------- SECURITY WARNING ----------------
warning: | TLS certificate verification has been disabled! |
warning: ---------------------------------------------------
warning: HTTPS connections may not be secure. See https://aka.ms/gcmcore-tlsverify for more information.
```

## Add Certificate to Windows Certificate Store

If the self-signed certificated has been imported to the Windows certificate store, you can simply execute this command:

```
git config --global http.sslbackend schannel
```

This will tell Git to read the certificates from the Windows certificate store. Keep in mind, this sometimes doesn't work (never worked for me for some reason). In such cases you can add the self-signed certificate to the OpenSSL certificate bundle.

## Add Certificate to OpenSSL Certificate Bundle

An advanced approach would be to add the self-signed certificate to Git trusted certificates bundle.

1. Obtain the self-signed certificate:

   ```
   openssl s_client -connect repo.domain.com:443
   ```

   Copy everything between (including)

   ```
   -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
   ...   
   -----END CERTIFICATE-----
   ```
2. Go to `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\usr\ssl\certs`, open the `ca-bundle.crt` file in your favorite editor and
   paste the certificate at the bottom:

   ```
   # My Company Certifiate
   -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
   ...   
   -----END CERTIFICATE-----
   ```
3. Configure Git to use `openssl` as a certificate provider:

   ```
   git config --global http.sslbackend openssl
   ```

   and set the path to the certificate bundle:

   ```
   git config --global http.sslcainfo C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\usr\ssl\certs\ca-bundle.crt
   ```
4. Clone your repository:

   ```
   git clone <your repo>
   ```

This is the optimal solution because we're getting the benefits of SSL verification and those obnoxious security warning messages won't be shown anymore.

---

If you're getting this error when setting a property value:

```
warning: http.sslverify has multiple values
error: cannot overwrite multiple values with a single value
       Use a regexp, --add or --replace-all to change http.sslVerify.
```

Open your `.gitconfig` file and remove duplicate `http.sslverify` lines or for whichever property it's complaining about.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to add the self-signed cert, export the cert you want as a Base-64 encoded .CER file.  Locate your Git cert.pem file (for me it is in `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\ssl\cert.pem`).  Open up your .CER file in a text-editor, and copy/paste the contents at the end of your cert.pem file.  Save the file.  Then open up your console and type

```
 git config --global http.sslCAInfo "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\ssl\cert.pem"
```

Comment: Even pointing to this the same error occurs. Any other work around ?

Answer (score 3):

If you are connected to a VPN, please try without the VPN. I go this error because of this issue.

Answer (score 2):

For github.com you may change protocol from HTTPS to SSH:

1. open .git/config
2. fix url in [remote "origin"] block

   old: url = https://github.com/myname/proj1

   new: url = git@github.com:myname/proj1.git

Answer (score 0):

This can be fixed by disabling SSL checking in the git config for the affected repositories. This should not require elevated privileges to complete.

```
git config http.sslVerify "false"
```

This command does not require use of the `--global` argument.

Comment: The trouble ticket I submitted to IT stated that "The git bash terminal was unable to access the URL of the repo which I could view from a browser in Bitbucket. The reason was an SSL certificate problem: 'self-signed certificate in certificate chain.'"

Answer (score 0):

It seemed like GIT was not configured by default to use the certificates in my Windows Trust Store. It worked for me by doing the following:

1. Close your Intellij
2. Open GIT Bash from the start menu and and run this command:
   `git config --global http.sslbackend schannel`
3. Reopen Intellij and try

Comment: Kyu Lee already suggested this nearly a year ago. Please don't repeat answers.