# SSL certificate error while cloning a git repo

Tags: git, ssl, certificate

When I try to clone a repo from git, I face **SSL certificate problem: self-signed certificate**

How is it possible to add a certificate to resolve this issue at MacOS

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make git accept a self signed certificate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621768/how-can-i-make-git-accept-a-self-signed-certificate)

Answer (score -1):

Have you create and add ssh key to your git hub account.
If not this will help you: https://help.github.com/en/enterprise/2.15/user/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account