# No error message has been provided by the native library Repository Clone Libgit2sharp

Tags: c#, libgit2sharp

Currently trying to clone a gitlab repository (which can only be accessed by VPN). A normal access (without vpn) through a gitlab repo works with libgit2sharp.

```
var localFolder = "test";
var gitLabUrl = "some url";
var userNamePasswordCredentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials()
{
    Username = gitConnection.UserName,
    Password = gitConnection.Password
};
Directory.CreateDirectory(localFolder);

var cloneOptions = new CloneOptions();
cloneOptions.CertificateCheck += (certificate, valid, host) => true;
try
{
     cloneOptions.CredentialsProvider = (_url, _user, _cred) => new DefaultCredentials();
     Repository.Clone(gitLabUrl, localFolder, cloneOptions);
}
catch (LibGit2SharpException ex)
{
    cloneOptions.CredentialsProvider = (_url, _user, _cred) => userNamePasswordCredentials;
    Repository.Clone(gitLabUrl, localFolder, cloneOptions);
}
 var repository = new Repository(localFolder);
```

I am getting an error:

> No error message has been provided by the native library

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to clone git repository by using the command:

```
git -c http.sslVerify=false clone https://example.com/path/to/git
```

Currently LibGit2Sharp doesnt have facility to clone git by turning sslVerify false. One way to turn this off was by using the code from this link:

https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/master/LibGit2Sharp.Tests/desktop/SmartSubtransportFixture.cs

```
SmartSubtransportRegistration<MockSmartSubtransport> registration = null;
RemoteCertificateValidationCallback certificateValidationCallback = (sender,
                            certificate, chain, errors) => { return true; };

try
{
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = certificateValidationCallback;
    registration = GlobalSettings.RegisterSmartSubtransport<MockSmartSubtransport>("https");

    var cloneOptions = new CloneOptions();
    cloneOptions.CertificateCheck += (certificate, valid, host) => true;

    cloneOptions.CredentialsProvider = (_url, _user, _cred) => new DefaultCredentials();
    Repository.Clone("https://url", "localFolder", cloneOptions);
  }
  finally
  {
      GlobalSettings.UnregisterSmartSubtransport(registration);
      ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback -= certificateValidationCallback;
  }
```

Some other links:

[How can I make git accept a self signed certificate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621768/how-can-i-make-git-accept-a-self-signed-certificate)