# Can't install DocTR OCR Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to install DocTR in Python, but I'm having issues from the start. I'm following step by step from the documentation (https://github.com/mindee/doctr).

Now I'm stuck here:

```
pip install -r demo/tf-requirements.txt
```

I get this error:

> Obtaining python-doctr[tf] from git+https://github.com/mindee/doctr.git#egg=python-doctr[tf] (from -r demo/tf-requirements.txt (line 1))
> Cloning https://github.com/mindee/doctr.git to c:\users\user\desktop\doctrtest\doctr\src\python-doctr
> Running command git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet https://github.com/mindee/doctr.git 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\DocTRTest\doctr\src\python-doctr'
> fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/mindee/doctr.git/': SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
> error: subprocess-exited-with-error
> × git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet https://github.com/mindee/doctr.git 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\DocTRTest\doctr\src\python-doctr' did not run successfully.
> │ exit code: 128
> ╰─> See above for output.
> note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
> error: subprocess-exited-with-error

I tried adding -"http.proxyStrictSSL": false- in the json and didn't work. I also downloaded the "win-ca" extension for vs code, and didn't work either.

I'm a little lost here so I'd appreciate any  help.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try temporarily disabling ssl verification for all repos using - `git config --global http.sslVerify false` before installing `doctr`. Revert back - `git config --global http.sslVerify true` afterwards. Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621768/how-can-i-make-git-accept-a-self-signed-certificate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're facing with SSL verification problem on Git & Pip.

You may try to ignore SSL certificate checks via:

`git config --global http.sslVerify false`

And then (just in case) run the install command via

```
pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org <package_name>
```

After the successful install, do not forget to open sslVerify:

`git config --global http.sslVerify true`