# git repo clone failed in IntelliJ Idea?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

My company's git repo is accessible and clonable via **Egit (Eclipse git)** but in **IntelliJ idea** , it is showing the error "**Repo test failed**" (even after adding **'username:password@'** before the repo url).The company network is backed up with a firewall but the git repo is hosted on company's site only , which can be browsed using any browser , so why the network is not allowing IntelliJ Idea to clone the repo ?

Comment: How can we know when there's nothing to look at?

Comment: What else do you need , comment and then I'll post !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how your proxies are set up - maybe IntelliJ is defaulting to using proxies and they're refusing to send the requests internally; alternatively, maybe it needs to go through the proxy and Eclipse is doing the right thing when IntelliJ isn't.

Comment: Is there a way to configure proxy settings in IntelliJ idea ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3557731/how-to-get-git-to-work-through-a-proxy-and-intellij-idea