# IntelliJ Idea & Github: Clone Failed

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea, version-control

Yesterday, when I tried to pull from github repository using IntelliJ Idea, it returned me the following error:

```
Clone Failed. Cannot fork() for git-remote-https: Resource temporarily unavailable.
```

When I use git from command prompt or from another IDE (like Netbeans), everything is OK. Can you help me?

OS: Windows 10 1511 x64.
Git: 2.5.3 cygwin64.
Idea: 15.0.2 Ultimate.

Comment: I think I'm missing something. If you can make it work using a console or an IDE, what is the tool that is showing that error?

Comment: @XavierÁlvarez I assume `intellij-idea` via tags.

Comment: @JonSurrell you are right. This error occurs specifically in IntelliJ Idea.

Comment: Can you please let us know the following.  Which OS are you on? Which git executable are you using in Intellij Idea? Is it the same as the one that Netbeans and the command line use? Which Intellij version are you using? It would be good to add the answer to the above questions to your question to help future readers answer your question.  The reason I ask about the git executable is, that I have seen similar 'fork'-ing problems when using Cygwin's git

Comment: which git? any firewall?

Comment: @vikingsteve Standard Windows firewall.

Comment: Does setting up http proxy help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3557731/how-to-get-git-to-work-through-a-proxy-and-intellij-idea

Comment: Please have a look at my answer below. Cygwin starts forking usually after installing/updating a package. Do you remember doing so recently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cygwin's forking issue is detailed [here](https://cygwin.com/faq-nochunks.html#faq.using.fixing-fork-failures)

To summarize the fix, try executing the following after closing Intellij AND after making sure that there are no other cygwin processes running:

```
$CYGWIN_HOME\bin\dash.exe -c '/usr/bin/rebaseall -v'
```

Also, you might need to install the rebase package by executing Cygwin's setup.exe if you haven't already got it. In this case, the steps are:

```
a. Install the Cygwin rebase package (if necessary)  
b. shutdown all Cygwin processes  
c. execute the command listed above
```

This problem has been reported before on the Cygwin mailing list: http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2015-10/msg00269.html, however read through the linked discussion only if the summarized instructions do not fix your problem

---

#### How to make sure that there are no Cygwin processes running?

Use Sysinternal's Process explorer as follows:

> [Microsoft/SysInternals Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) - Go to Find > Find
>   Handle or DLL. In the "Handle or DLL substring:" text box, type the
>   path to the file (e.g. "C:\path\to\file.txt") and click "Search".